# Changing the zone number in "UTMZone11" as used in GeoGridPosition

Tags: functions, replacement

I can compute which UTM zone a point is in, given its longitude.  I want to convert the geographic coordinates (latitude, longitude) to UTM in WGS84.  This seems to involve my inserting a coordinate system spec like "UTMZone11" (e.g., `utm = GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{lat, long, elev}], "UTMZone11"]`

If the next record contains a coordinate that is in a different UTM zone, how can I change the 11 in "UTMZone11" to the different zone number?  Is there some sort of mask or dummy variable or other practice/strategy for changing the number within the "UTMZone11"?

Answer (score 3):

The U.S. National Imagery and Mapping Agency (NIMA) (formerly the Defense Mapping Agency) adopted a special grid for military use throughout the world called the Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM) grid. In this grid, the world is divided into 60 north-south zones, each covering a strip 6° wide in longitude. These zones are numbered consecutively beginning with Zone 1, between 180° and 174° west longitude, and eastward to Zone 60, between 174° and 180° east longitude. UTM zones are defined between 80° south latitude and 84° north latitude. Reference: [U.S. Geological Survey](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/what-does-term-utm-mean-utm-better-or-more-accurate-latitudelongitude?qt-news_science_products=0#qt-news_science_products).

Here's a way to convert a longitude to a UTM Zone using a `NearestFunction` which matches a longitude in degrees to the nearest center longitude of each of the 60 UTM zones. The zone names from `GeoProjectionData["UTMZone"]` are associated with their center longitudes, for example, `"UTMZone19" -> -69°` (see: `Longitude[GeoProjectionData["UTMZone19", "Centering"]]` is -69°)

```
nf = Nearest[
  AssociationThread[#, Longitude[GeoProjectionData[#, "Centering"]] &/@ #] &@
  GeoProjectionData["UTMZone"][[;;60]]]
```

Use `nf` to convert from longitude in degrees to UTMZone. Notice that the `NearestFunction` returns a list, and that when the latitude is exactly on the boundary between two zones, the list has two values. UTM zones are numbered from 180° west longitude eastward to 180° east longitude, so using the first value from the function gives the desired UTMZone.

```
nf[Quantity[16, "AngularDegrees"]]
(* {UTMZone33} *)
nf[Quantity[84, "AngularDegrees"]]
(* {UTMZone44, UTMZone45} *)
```

Combine `nf` with the `Longitude` function for a flexible method to convert `GeoPosition` data and locations to UTMZone.

```
nf[Longitude[{84, 0}]]//First (*latitude, longitude list to UTMZone*)
(* UTMZone30 *)
nf[Longitude[Entity["City", {"Washington", "DistrictOfColumbia", "UnitedStates"}]]]//First
(* UTMZone18 *)
nf[Longitude[GeoPosition[{64.5057, -165.415}]]]//First (*GeoPosition to UTMZone*)
(* UTMZone03 *)
```

For latitudes in the southern hemisphere, join "South" to the UTM zone, e.g., `First@nf[Longitude[GeoPosition[{-35.31, 149.13}]]] <> "South"` returns `UTMZone55South`.